# Python Plotly: Surface autocolorscale property is True but throws Value Error 'must be specified as a bool'

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to make a Python Plotly 3D plot in which I want to add a polygon at height 0 (as part of a plot with more elements in 3D).
Here `poly` is the 2D polygon, `the3dshape` is a part of the larger 3D shape.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# define coordinate lists
xlist_a = np.array([171500. 171600. 171600. 171500. 171500. 171500. 171600. 171600.])
ylist_a = np.array([440800. 440800. 440900. 440900. 440800. 440900. 440900. 441000.])
zlist_a = np.array([-23.3  -23.3  -23.3  -23.3  -23.3  -23.93 -23.93 -23.93])

xlist_b = np.array([173085.02597165, 173130.68942919, 173125.12606874, 173089.70382315,
        173086.55869285, 173076.64002678]),
ylist_b = np.array([442049.32278434, 442020.02737907, 442011.55155576, 442034.77606562,
        442030.31434249, 442036.49772171]),
zlist_b =  np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])


poly = go.Surface(x = xlist,y = ylist,z = zlist,autocolorscale = True)
the3dshape = go.Mesh3d(x=xlist3d,y=ylist3d,z=zlist3d,alphahull=0, 
        colorscale = [[0,'rgb(255,217,47)'],
                      [1,'rgb(255,217,47)']],
        intensity = np.linspace(1, 1, 8, endpoint=True))

fig = go.Figure(data=the3dshape)
fig.add_surface(poly)
fig.show()
```

But it throws a Value Error saying I should define the `autocolorscale` as a bool (True or False) while I actually did define the `autocolorscale`.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-834ff6cdde5b> in <module>()
     36 # othermesh = go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, color='green', opacity=0.20, alphahull=3)
     37 fig = go.Figure(data=the3dshape)
---> 38 fig.add_surface(poly)
     39 # fig.update_traces(surfaceaxis = 2)
     40 fig.show()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/_plotly_utils/basevalidators.py in raise_invalid_val(self, v, inds)
    281                 typ=type_str(v),
    282                 v=repr(v),
--> 283                 valid_clr_desc=self.description(),
    284             )
    285         )

ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'plotly.graph_objs.Surface' received for the 'autocolorscale' property of surface
        Received value: Surface({
    'autocolorscale': True,
    'x': array([173085.02597165, 173130.68942919, 173125.12606874, 173089.70382315,
                173086.55869285, 173076.64002678]),
    'y': array([442049.32278434, 442020.02737907, 442011.55155576, 442034.77606562,
                442030.31434249, 442036.49772171]),
    'z': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
})

    The 'autocolorscale' property must be specified as a bool
    (either True, or False)
```

Maybe the parameter is nested into some other parameter, but the error message does not say anything about that, and I cannot find anything about it in the [documentation on autocolorscale](https://plotly.com/python/reference/mesh3d/#mesh3d-autocolorscale).

How can I fix this plot?

Comment: You seem to have left out the part of the traceback that tells us exactly where the error occurred.  I don't think it's within the code fragment you posted - your creation of `poly` apparently worked, but then you somehow passed `poly` as the value for the `autocolorscale` parameter elsewhere.

Comment: Updated the question to provide more context about the error and the specific situation in my code

Comment: The first parameter of `Figure.add_surface()` is `autocolorscale` - *that's* where you're passing an inappropriate value (`poly`), not the place where you explicitly mention `autocolorscale` in your code.  You need to explicitly name that parameter, although I didn't see at first glance any parameters to `add_surface()` for which `poly` would be a reasonable value.  I think this method wants your x, y, z data directly, rather than you creating a `Surface` separately.